# Php giving internal error with header()

Tags: php

Here is my code

I keep getting a 500 internal error meaning it is a sever sided error but not sure what it could be?

```
<?php include "dbConfig.php";

$msg = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $password = sha1s($_POST["password"]);
     if ($name == '' || $password == '') {
        $msg = "You must enter all fields";
    } else {


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usrs WHERE username = '$name' AND pw = '$password'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);

        if ($query === false) {
            echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

            header("Location: http://www.google.com");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: check your logs ,log contains main reasn of this error

Comment: `<?php include "dbConfig.php";` change it to `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);include "dbConfig.php";`

Comment: is your table name `usrs` or it is `user`??

Comment: Is `sha1s ` one of your custom functions defined in dbConfig.php. If not this should be the reason for the error. Php has a predifined function `sha1` to calculate the hash of a string. Check your log files for more errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function `sha1s` in line number 6 of your code. If this is not defined in your `dbConfig.php` this should be the reason for the error. PHP has an inbuilt function [sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) to hash strings if you are looking for it.

Also check your error logs for more errors. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) for getting useful error messages in php